# Wildfly HornetQ Remote HTTP connection memory leak

Tags: memory, https, connection, wildfly, hornetq

I am running Wildfly 8.2 instance with HornetQ messaging remotely accessible via HTTPS on port 8185.

For testing the connection I am running a client on the same machine connecting via https-remoting://localhost:8185

- from client view everything works fine: connecting, sending / receiving messages and closing connection
- on server side at first all works fine, too. However, after period set in "connection-ttl" of RemoteConnectionFactory has passed, server logs following lines:

  ```
  2015-09-03 17:05:49,152 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.client] (hornetq-failure-check-thread) HQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: HQ119014: Did not receive data from /192.168.160.83:63937. It is likely the client has exited or crashed without closing its connection, or the network between the server and client has failed. You also might have configured connection-ttl and client-failure-check-period incorrectly. Please check user manual for more information. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
  2015-09-03 17:05:49,154 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (hornetq-failure-check-thread) HQ221021: failed to remove connection
  ```

Final result after testing for a longer time (every 1-2 seconds clients are connecting, sending / receiving messages, closing the connection):

- Wildfly consumes more and more heap memory and finally stops working with an OutOfMemoryError ...
- As mentioned, the connections are always explicitly closed by client, and at closing time no error is logged, neither on client nor on server side. It seems that the "hornetq-failure-check-thread" just didn't get informed that the connection was already closed

Any help for this issue is appreciated!